# hover does not work after dropdown class delete

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap template I am practising on. In the navbar there is "Blog" and "Test"

On the test button, I removed the `li class="dropdown "`, because I wanted to try to make a button where the hover is active like on the "blog" button. But when I hover over the test, the text only display blue, on there is *not* a white background.

I cannot figure out how I can make that work? I have to make a CSS class for a button on the navbar, who does not have a dropdown.

For fun sake I tried to delete all the CSS, but the hover was still working on the blog button.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
<!-- main-menu -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
    <li class="dropdown ">
        <a href="blog-large-image-right-sidebar.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ><a href="index-blog.html">Blog Home <span class="badge">v1.1</span></a></li>
            <li ><a href="index-blog-2.html">Blog Home 2 <span class="badge">NEW</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
    <li>
        <a href="blog-large-image-right-sidebar.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Test</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ><a href="index-blog.html">Blog Home <span class="badge">v1.1</span></a></li>
            <li ><a href="index-blog-2.html">Blog Home 2 <span class="badge">NEW</span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown ">
                <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Large Image</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu to-left">
                    <li ><a href="blog-large-image-right-sidebar.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="blog-large-image-left-sidebar.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="blog-large-image-no-sidebar.html">Without Sidebar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown ">
                <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Medium Image</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu to-left">
                    <li ><a href="blog-medium-image-right-sidebar.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="blog-medium-image-left-sidebar.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="blog-medium-image-no-sidebar.html">Without Sidebar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown ">
                <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Masonry</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu to-left">
                    <li ><a href="blog-masonry-right-sidebar.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="blog-masonry-left-sidebar.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="blog-masonry-no-sidebar.html">Without Sidebar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li ><a href="blog-timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
            <li ><a href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: just add `.nav navbar-nav > li:hover { background:#fff }` in ur stylesheet

Comment: You are not getting the white background on blog either..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion MJN. That one is not working. Leo the lion: the white is working on blog. Just checked it

Answer (score 1):

To style your links within navigation menus you have to add one of these lines in your CSS file according to your HTML 
(1) if the main parent div is .navbar-collapse:

```
    .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>li a{background-color:#fff;}
```

(2) if the main parent is Navbar-default:

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li a {background-color:#fff;}
```

(3) if the main parent is navbar-inverse:

```
     .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li a{background-color:#fff;}
```

And something like this depending on the main parent class and the class with in ul tag